# Django filter: pass and array for an OR statement?

Tags: django

I want to query a set with Django with the filter function. The problem is that I want to pass a list of possible values for a given column.

I know I can do the following:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(username='whatever') | Q(username='whatever2') | (username='whatever3') | ..... )
```

But the problem is that I have a list of possible usernames.

What I have so far is:

```
users = []
for username in usernames:
    users.extend(User.objects.filter(username=username))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this (make one database query instead of multiples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=usernames)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in